# Laravel Pagination "Three Dots" Separator customization

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5.3

Im currently using Laravel 5.3 and was wondering if there is a option for the customization of the Three Dots deperator. (skips page 9-10, which is to late)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoT0v.png)

Currently the Three dots initiate if there are more than 11 pages... Which isnt quiet useful if your site is responsive. if there are to many pages so it breaks into 2 lines.

[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYXTW.png)

I cannot find anything regarding there being options for $resource->links(). But if there is please tell me! Much appreciated.

Edit: it has to do with the following function:
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.php (page: 128, render()). The current function does not support a second variable. So i guess i have to rebuild it?

Comment: you can do `php artisan vendor:publish`and this create files in `resources\views\vendors\paginations`so you can customize the page you need (bootstrap, bootstrap4 etc) for pagination

Comment: Yeah but this is sadly only the front end. It doesnt quiet allow me to say which page will be dotted out. Since paginate doesnt allow a second paramater.

Answer (score 9):

This is a solution for Laravel 5.5+. Here is what it does:

- Shows the first and the last page.
- Shows previous and next two pages from the current page.
- Three dots only appear on the left after the current page is greater than 4.
- Three dots only appear on the right after the current page is less than the 4 - (count of pages).

```html
<!-- Pagination Elements -->
@foreach ($elements as $element)
    <!-- Array Of Links -->
    @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
        <!--  Use three dots when current page is greater than 4.  -->
        @if ($paginator->currentPage() > 4 && $page === 2)
            <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link">...</span></li>
        @endif

        <!--  Show active page else show the first and last two pages from current page.  -->
        @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
            <li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link">{{ $page }}</span></li>
        @elseif ($page === $paginator->currentPage() + 1 || $page === $paginator->currentPage() + 2 || $page === $paginator->currentPage() - 1 || $page === $paginator->currentPage() - 2 || $page === $paginator->lastPage() || $page === 1)
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
        @endif

        <!--  Use three dots when current page is away from end.  -->
        @if ($paginator->currentPage() < $paginator->lastPage() - 3 && $page === $paginator->lastPage() - 1)
            <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link">...</span></li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**Output:**

[Page 1 (first page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aixfu.png)

[Page 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTJyU.png)

[Page 10 (last page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjG7T.png)

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1 :**
You can customize default files but don't change vendor files directly. Publish them and then add modifications to that.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

This command will automatically create the folder /resources/views/vendor/pagination and you have your files for modification.
You can get more information here : [laravel pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view)

**Option 2:**

Maybe you want to get rid of the files that are generated by default. Or, perhaps you want to assign another file to be responsible for your default pagination view.

All of this is possible, but you will need to inform the AppServiceProvider for this action by calling the new pagination views in the boot() method:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot(){
    Paginator::defaultView('your-pagination-view-file-name');

    Paginator::defaultSimpleView('your-pagination-view-file-name');
}
```

Get information for defaultView and defaultSimpleView here :[laravel pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view)

I have created new file for pagination and added in AppServiceProvider.

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
<ul class="blog-pagenation">
    {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
    @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
        <li class="disabled"><a>«</a></li>
    @else
        <li><a href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" rel="prev">«</a></li>
    @endif

    @if($paginator->currentPage() > 3)
        <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="{{ $paginator->url(1) }}">1</a></li>
    @endif
    @if($paginator->currentPage() > 4)
        <li><a>...</a></li>
    @endif
    @foreach(range(1, $paginator->lastPage()) as $i)
        @if($i >= $paginator->currentPage() - 2 && $i <= $paginator->currentPage() + 2)
            @if ($i == $paginator->currentPage())
                <li class="active"><a class="active">{{ $i }}</a></li>
            @else
                <li><a href="{{ $paginator->url($i) }}">{{ $i }}</a></li>
            @endif
        @endif
    @endforeach
    @if($paginator->currentPage() < $paginator->lastPage() - 3)
        <li><a>...</a></li>
    @endif
    @if($paginator->currentPage() < $paginator->lastPage() - 2)
        <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="{{ $paginator->url($paginator->lastPage()) }}">{{ $paginator->lastPage() }}</a></li>
    @endif

    {{-- Next Page Link --}}
    @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
        <li><a href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next">»</a></li>
    @else
        <li class="disabled"><a>»</a></li>
    @endif
</ul>
@endif
```

By using this i am able to get 3 dots in starting and ending you have to customize classes based on your themes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous response, once you generate the vendor view files with the artisan command **php artisan vendor:publish** you can create a new one in that folder and call it for example **custom.blade.php** and put the following code:

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
<ul class="custom-pagination">
    {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
    @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
        <li class="disabled pageNumber"><span>&laquo; Prev</span></li>
    @else
        <li><a class="pageNumber" href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" rel="prev">&laquo;</a></li>
    @endif

    {{-- Pagination Elements --}}
    @foreach ($elements as $element)
        {{-- Array Of Links --}}
        @if (is_array($element))
            @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                @if ($page === $paginator->currentPage())
                    <li class="active pageNumber"><span>{{ $page }}</span></li>
                @elseif (($page === $paginator->currentPage() + 1 || $page === $paginator->currentPage() + 2)
                 || $page === $paginator->lastPage())
                    <li><a class="pageNumber" href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
                @elseif ($page === $paginator->lastPage()-1)
                    <li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach

    {{-- Next Page Link --}}
    @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
        <li><a class="pageNumber" href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next">Next &raquo;</a></li>
    @else
        <li class="disabled pageNumber"><span>Next &raquo;</span></li>
    @endif
</ul>@endif
```

The important part of the code for the three dots is in the {{-- Array Of Links --}} portion. I think this more or less does what you need but may require additional tweaking.

then you can use it in your view like this:

```
<div class="pagination">
    @if ($users instanceof \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator)
        {{ $users->links('vendor.pagination.custom') }}
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: Not relevant for Laravel 5.4, where the 3 dots text is an actual element in the `$elements` collection which is sent with the `Paginator` object, and is recognized in the blade view with: `@if (is_string($element))`, as can be seen in [the source on GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/default.blade.php#L13)